# Error en If Msql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer un if existe tal condicion que me haga esto si no que me haga otra cosa pero no me sale en Mysql

```
 create procedure login(
 in _usuario varchar(50),
 in _pass varchar(50)
 )
 begin
IF (SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE usuario=_usuario and pass=_pass) THEN
   begin
   select 1;
   end;
   else
   begin
   select 2;
   end;
   end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto al error que tienes, lo que ocurre es que el `IF` valida condiciones Verdaderas o Falsas y lo que está recibiendo una consulta.

La clausula que buscas es [`EXISTS()`](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.0/es/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tb_admin WHERE usuario=_usuario and pass=_pass)
BEGIN
   ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

**Nota:** Como solo necesitas validar si la consulta es válida (recupera filas) no necesitas leer todas las columnas simplemente un `SELECT 1 FROM ....` alcanza.

Comment: me sale error igual:  
 
 alter procedure login(
 in _usuario varchar(50),
 in _pass varchar(50)
 )
begin
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE usuario=_usuario and pass=_pass)
BEGIN
   select 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select 1
END
end

Comment: @Alex, ¿que error te sale?

Comment: 0 32 11:31:28 alter procedure login(
  in _usuario varchar(50),
  in _pass varchar(50)
  )
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE usuario=_usuario and pass=_pass)
 BEGIN
    select 0
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
     select 1
 END Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
  in _usuario varchar(50),
  in _pass varchar(50)
  )
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb_' at line 1 0.797 sec

Comment: @Alex, puedes probar en primer lugar todo el código fuera del trigger, para ver que sea válido y haga lo que esperas?

Answer (score 0):

El error te viene por no rodear con comillas los campos _usuario y _pass

```
    create procedure login(
 in _usuario varchar(50),
 in _pass varchar(50)
 )
 begin
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tb_admin WHERE
 usuario='_usuario' and pass='_pass') THEN
  begin
   select 1;
   end;
   else
   begin
   select 2;
   end;
  end if;
  end;
```